# Vesta Panel phpMyAdmin .sql upload limit

Tags: digital-ocean, sql-limit, vesta

I use Digitalocean the server. I founded Vesta Hosting Panel. Do not increment the phpMyAdmin .sql dump helps limit?

- Note: I am a web designer. I'm new on the server does not work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Mostly dump size exceed the default php limits. I think increasing your "post_max_size" and "upload_max_filesize" will work. Maybe 64M should be enough. 
Just nano or vi /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and set

post_max_size = 64M

upload_max_filesize = 64M

and then just restart your apache..

Note:
If you are using CentOS or RHEL, then the php.in location is /etc/php.ini

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't got it to work, try this:

```
mysql -u (username) -p (database name ) < /path/to/sql/on/server
```

then enter user password when prompted, if its successful it will not output any message just go back to your phpmyadmin and refresh the page.